# OpenCageData geocoder: automatically update place name on marker drag

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geocoding

I am using the combination of:

- OpenStreetMaps
- Leaflet.js
- Leaflet Routing Machine + [lrm-tomtom](https://github.com/mrohnstock/lrm-tomtom) plugin (routing done using [TomTom API](https://developer.tomtom.com/))

and now I have decided to switch from `Nominatim` geocoder (which is default in LRM) to [OpenCageData geocoder](https://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api). They do have plugin for Leaflet, works fine except one minor thing:

> When I drag the marker to change the route, the geocoder input is updated in form of coordinates, like on the image below, whereas Nominatim updates the place name automatically.

[image]

Is there any way to implement same functionality for OpenCageData geocoder? I guess there should be but haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found a workaround, in the LRM changed the default `_update: function()` code

```
    var wp = this._waypoint,
    value = wp && wp.name ? wp.name : '';
    this.setValue(value);
    this.fire('reversegeocoded', {waypoint: wp, value: value});
```

to

```
        var wp = this._waypoint,
            value = wp && wp.name ? wp.name : '';
        var g = L.Control.OpenCageSearch.geocoder({key: "my-key", limit: 1});
        var q = this._waypoint.latLng.lat+','+this._waypoint.latLng.lng;
        var p = this;
        g.geocode(q, function(r) {
            if (r.length > 0) {
                wp.name = value = r[0].name;
            }
            p.setValue(value);
            p.fire('reversegeocoded', {waypoint: wp, value: value});
        })
```